# Architecture questions with Crawler Algorithm using Python

Tags: python, algorithm, architecture, web-crawler

Right now I have simple web crawler what takes page by url, puts it url to visited list (also writes a record to DB), finds urls on page, and put them to list of not visited if they are not in visited list. Then it takes url from not visited.

Simple.

But slow. It uses only 2-3% of CPU on DigitalOcean's smallest instance. And visited list constantly grows. If I start python interpriter (2.7x32) and create a list with urls-like strings then it will take about 0.5 GB of RAM. Not good. Also I'd like to remove url from visited list after some time to parse it again (information could be changed)

So I have several questions about ammending this process.
How to save state of process to be sure it will restart quickly and do not go over every visited url if some outage happens.

How to share qurrent state between crawlers:

- create a RabbitMQ queue and put urls to visit in it
- use some global python object of queue to use it "inside" and share between workers in different threads

?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the size of your `(not)visiteUrls` structure by implementing a [Least recently used caching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used). You can restrict it's size so that it drops the oldest url when it reaches the limit. This way your crawler won't occupy more than X ram. Tweaking the cache size would result in balancing between the memory and the chance of checking a visited url again.

To preserve the state - the simplest solution I could think of is to write the cache to a file periodically. For example a single url at a line. It will be easy to parse too. I guess it would be quite slow but it's a starting point and you can make it once in a few minutes. You shouldn't worry about the stored version not being the most accurate/recent because you already drop urls from the cache and they would eventually be visited again at some point.